# How to create snapshot of DOM element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas, scale

I am developing book editor application which is similar to ibooks author, google slides. So whatever the data user entered in right side editable area, we need to show the small snapshot of the page in left side tree view. we may need to update the snapshot very frequently. Editable area may contain video,image,textarea etc..

I found some solutions which converts html2canvas. Is it possible to create good quality snapshot without canvas, using only css3 scaling and javascript. if possible which is the best solution for the performance(with canvas or without canvas)?

I would appreciate if someone can link the related articles or github code.

Answer (score 0):

Only CSS3 & JavaScript...

hmmmmm...If its just for display purposes (rather than exporting a screenshot), you could just duplicate the editable screen elements on the snapshot div, but scaled down using CSS3:

```
  // the snapshot div contains the same elements & layout as
  // the editable div, but the snapshot div is 1/5 the size
  // because of the scale transformation.

  #snapshot{
      -moz-transform: scale(0.20);
      -ms-transform: scale(0.20); /* IE 9 */
      -webkit-transform: scale(0.20); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      transform: scale(0.20);
  }
```

Comment: Hmmm I tried this solution but the quality of the text is rally bad. I mean components were blurred.

Comment: Fair enough! There are other solutions. One canvas solution you've already mentioned in your question: html2canvas. It's...just ok...as long as the html content is simple with no fancy css applied--otherwise your html2canvas renderings might be different from the more complex original. Another solution is to send your html up to a headless browser on the server and have the server convert the html to a snapshot image. PhantomJS has worked well for me as a headless browser: http://phantomjs.org/  Good luck with your project!